Astronomical Dating in Biblical Prophecy
Does anyone have any good resources on Astronomical dating of Biblical prophecy? I have been looking into how Daniel and John used Astronomical "signs" to date their prophecies and have made several interesting connections. But I need more information on how these prophets use the descriptions of their visions to relate with astronomical positions of the stars and planets.

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Could you please give us an example of how the apostle John used "astronomical dating" and is this from the book of Revelation?

To the best of my knowledge, neither Daniel, nor the Revelation, conclusively date the expected fulfillment of their prophecies, astronomically or otherwise. Daniel has the vague reference to seventy weeks in Daniel 9:24, but this is a very difficult passage. There are a great many interpretations concerning the enumeration of these seventy weeks. Revelation gives what appears to be Christ’s horoscope. It has the sun and moon in Virgo, with Virgo in the ascendant (the “woman” brought forth the man child). But this is just an interpretation and could certainly be incorrect. I don’t know of any other astronomical occurrences in the Revelation that might be used to date its fulfillment.
If you’re looking to establish dates in order to put together a reliable chronology by which you can attempt to date something like Daniel, Ptolemy’s Almagest in conjunction with the Egyptian Annus Vagus and the Assyrian Kings list will help determine dates and reigns.
But truth be told, Daniel gives the year of reign for those in power during the time period of his prophecy. And Revelation specifies that of seven kings, the sixth was currently in power (Claudius).
Perhaps you could clarify and/or elaborate on your question. It’s not entirely clear what you’re after.

Surely the sixth (counting from Julius) was Nero, in keeping with ch1 v9, which associates the writing with a time of persecution? But perhaps "Claudius" was a slip of the pen.

People typically overlook Marc Antony. Following the defeat of Brutus and Cassius at the battle of Philippi, the empire was divided. Octavian took the west, and Antony the east. Josephus says that Octavian and Antony ruled together for fourteen years. Later Caesars are descended from Antony, who was also married into Caesar’s family after the treaty at Brundisium. From a Jewish perspective specifically, Antony would be one of the seven, who was the direct ruler over the east. It would be Julius Caesar (the head wounded), Marc Antony, Augustus, Tiberius, Caligula, Claudius, and Nero.

A parallel can also be drawn with Daniel. His beast has ten horns, and then an eleventh horn that pushes three out of the way. 1) Julius Caesar, 2) Marc Antony, 3) Octavian/Augustus, 4) Tiberius, 5) Caius/Caligula, 6) Claudius, 7) Nero, 8) Galba, 9) Otho, 10) Vitellius, and then 11) Vespasian, who pushed Galba, Otho, and Vitellius out of the way, becoming sole emperor and first of the Flavian line. Revelation even specifies an eighth king rather than the eighth king. Vespasian was eighth in authority, eleventh in order, was sent by one of the seven, and brought destruction to Jerusalem.

Michael Heiser has a YouTube video explaining Revelation 12 in an astrological context.
How does Revelation help pinpoint the birth of Christ?
Social-Science Commentary on the Book of Revelation by Malina has some astronomy.
Creation and Chaos in the Primeval Era and the Eschaton: A Religio-Historical Study of Genesis 1 and Revelation 12 (The Biblical Resource Series by Gunkel) also has some. –
